# Seperate two different delimiter and cut off

Tags: r, delimiter, strsplit

I have a tibble, e.g.

`a <- as_tibble(c("201.1, 202 (abc) 203, 204", "301 / 302.22 def, 303"))`

```
  value                  
  <chr>                  
1 201.1, 202 (abc) 203, 204
2 301 / 302.22 def, 303
```

Now I would like to get a data.frame with two columns

```
[1,] 201.1  202
[2,] 301    302.22
```

by cutting everything after the second number (202 in the first row, 302.22 in the second row) *and* separating the remining part of the expression with delimiter "," or "/" to get the two columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are several approaches.

**1) separate** Use `separate` from tidyr like this giving the tibble/data.frame shown.  It automatically determines that the columns are numeric.

```
library(tidyr)

a %>%
  separate("value", c("value1", "value2"), sep = "[,/ ]+",
    extra = "drop", convert = TRUE)

## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##   value1 value2
##    <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1   201.   202 
## 2   301    302.
```

**2) Base R**  Use `strcapture` from base R like this.  No packages are needed.

```
strcapture("([0-9.]+)[^0-9.]+([0-9.]+).*", a$value, 
  data.frame(value1 = numeric(0), value2 = numeric(0)))

##   value1 value2
## 1  201.1 202.00
## 2  301.0 302.22
```

**3) read.pattern** Use `read.pattern` from gsubfn.  This uses the same regex as in (2).  It automatically determines that the columns are numeric and uses the same `text=` and `col.names=` arguments as `read.table` making them easy to remember if you are familiar with that.

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = a$value, pattern = "([0-9.]+)[^0-9.]+([0-9.]+).*", 
  col.names = c("value1", "value2"))

##   value1 value2
## 1  201.1 202.00
## 2  301.0 302.22
```

### Note

The input from the question

```
library(tibble)
a <- as_tibble(c("201.1, 202 (abc) 203, 204", "301 / 302.22 def, 303"))
```

Comment: Thanks for `strcapture`, I didn't know about that and it seems really useful.

Comment: A good answer with several nice options - interesting to learn that `.` doesn't need to be escaped inside a character identifier `[]`.

Comment: Great! I hoped to get such an answer using tidyr and separate

Answer (score 2):

My attempt:

```
b <- stringr::str_extract(a$value, "([\\.\\d]+)\\D+([\\.\\d]+)\\D+.*", group = c(1, 2))
```

the regex is intended to be:

capturing group 1 = one or more [digits or .s]
then one or more non-digits
then capturing group 2 = one or more [digits or .s]
then one or more non-digits
then any number of other characters

return just capturing groups 1 and 2.

edit:
As per the other answers, I have needlessly escaped the `.` inside the `[]` so this can be simplified by replacing each `[\\.\\d]+` with `[0-9.]+` which for me at least is more readable at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(a$value, \(i) { 
            i1 <- regmatches(i, gregexpr("\\d+\\.?\\d*", i))[[1]]; return(i1[c(1, 2)])}))

     [,1]    [,2]    
[1,] "201.1" "202"   
[2,] "301"   "302.22"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)

stri_extract_all(a$value, regex = "(\\.|[0-9])+") |> 
  lapply(\(x) as.numeric(head(x, 2L))) |> 
  transpose() |> 
  setNames(c("a", "b")) |>
  as.data.frame()


#       a      b
# 1 201.1 202.00
# 2 301.0 302.22
```